# How to get unsubscribe and subscribe words on the toggle button using angular2 or typescript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

i have a toggle button, in which i had given `subscribe` on the thumb of the toggle, and i had enabled it by default. So, when i disable the toggle button, then it must show word `unsubscribe` on the button.. So, i want the thumb of toggle button to show `subscribe` when it is enabled and `unsubscribe` when disabled. Please help.

HTML:

```
<md-slide-toggle class="showToggle" name="subscribe"required></md-slide-toggle>
```

CSS:

```
.toggle{
  margin: auto;
}
.toggle .mat-slide-toggle{
  margin: auto auto auto 70px;
}
.toggle .mat-slide-toggle-bar{
  padding: 20px 100px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  background-color: #654898 ;
}
.toggle .mat-slide-toggle-thumb{
  padding: 10px 50px 30px 50px;
  background-color: #b755ff ;
  border-radius: 25px;
  top: 3px !important;
  border:1px solid white;
}
.toggle .mat-slide-toggle-thumb:before{
  content: 'subscribe';
  margin-left:-28px !important;
}
.toggle .mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked .mat-slide-toggle-thumb-container{
  padding: 10px 70px;
}
.toggle input[type=checkbox], .toggle input[type=radio]{
  margin: 7px 0 0 !important;
}
```

Ts:

```
public device:boolean = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that simply :

```
<mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="device" #slider>
  {{ slider.checked ? 'Unsubscribe' : 'Subscribe' }}
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkslider-label-change)**

---

Older version :

Just added style :

```
.showToggle.mat-checked .mat-slide-toggle-thumb:before{
  content: 'unsubscribe';
  margin-left:-28px !important;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-slide-older?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks for the response.. i need in md-slide-toggle

Comment: Both are same , you can try this code with `md-slide-toggle` , `mat-slide-toggle` is just newer version.

Comment: i tried but not coming, i had uploaded the image.. I need unsubscribe to come on button when it gets unchecked

Comment: @Bhrungarajni, do one thing create a demo as we did and we'll solve that issue on that.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wohxyw?file=main.ts, this demo is working according to my requirement but not working on my system

Comment: i have used angular material of "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.2", is this the problem?

Comment: No that's not also the issue , we can also make your code working but how can we debug without seeing working ?

Comment: @Bhrungarajni, you should use the latest version , the version you are using is deprecated

Comment: if i change the version then all other things will go off.. is there any way to try with that?

Comment: Unfortunately not , try to set up a demo with your version or provide me module file and packages with version , i'll try to set it up.

Comment: ya i will.. is it possible to send module file here? i will update module and package in the question itself

Comment: i am sorry for asking you more doubts.. i have no idea about gist, can you pls guide accordingly i will do.. is that git hub?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163300/discussion-between-vivek-doshi-and-bhrungarajni).

Answer (score 1):

You can add 2 new CSS rules:

```
::ng-deep .toggle.subscribe .mat-slide-toggle-thumb:before{
  content: 'subscribe';
}
::ng-deep .toggle.unsubscribe .mat-slide-toggle-thumb:before{
  content: 'unsubscribe';
}
```

The most interesting parts for us are `.toggle.subscribe` and `.toggle.unsubscribe`. To enable/disable this rules we need to add `subscribe` or `unsubscribe` classes to our `ul` element, and based on this classes, one of the rules above will be applied. We can trigger classes using `[ngClass]`:

```
<ul class="toggle" [ngClass]="{'subscribe': device, 'unsubscribe': !device}">
```

You can change CSS and add `[ngClass]` to any other element, I worked with `ul` just for example.

And here is the working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wohxyw?file=app/slide-toggle-overview-example.html

Comment: I need the same way as it is working in demo, but i had used md-slide toggle, so it is not working with mw

Comment: i had used "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.2", this version, is that the problem?

Comment: @Bhrungarajni I didn't do anything, what can differ in material versions. The only thing: try to use `/deep/` instead of `::ng-deep`.

Comment: i tried as you said but my toggle button css is not seen.. it is fully small

Comment: is it like this you suggested me to try? /deep/ .toggle.subscribe .mat-slide-toggle-thumb:before{
  content: 'subscribe';
}
/deep/ .toggle.unsubscribe .mat-slide-toggle-thumb:before{
  content: 'unsubscribe';
}

Comment: @Bhrungarajni, yes

Comment: @Bhrungarajni may be the issue is somewhere else, I can't really say without live example

Comment: @Bhrungarajni you have the main idea, all you need is just to adapt this code for your Material version